# How to interpret VIF in this case?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I wrote some codes which use a multi linear model to predicts the Price for a car from features including Mileage, Cylinder, Doors, Cruise, Sound, Leather data. Sample data as in the snapshot: [cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5reVu.png) Then I want to check whether there are any of the features in the model that are highly colinear and whether they impact the model quality, as below, the result I got is an array ( I suppose it's a VIF array?), however, my understanding is that each VIF value should represent the colinearity between each two of the features, that means, it should be a matrix instead of array right? How do I check the colinearity from the array? Or I should change my codes somehow to get a matrix? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import scipy, scipy.stats
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')
cars.head()
cars.info()
X=cars[['Mileage', 'Cylinder', 'Doors', 'Cruise', 'Sound', 'Leather']].values
y=cars['Price'].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
[variance_inflation_factor(X_train, j) for j in range(X_train.shape[1])]
```

---

output I got:
    #cars.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 804 entries, 0 to 803
Data columns (total 18 columns):
Price          804 non-null float64
Mileage        804 non-null int64
Cylinder       804 non-null int64
Doors          804 non-null int64
Cruise         804 non-null int64
Sound          804 non-null int64
Leather        804 non-null int64
Buick          804 non-null int64
Cadillac       804 non-null int64
Chevy          804 non-null int64
Pontiac        804 non-null int64
Saab           804 non-null int64
Saturn         804 non-null int64
convertible    804 non-null int64
coupe          804 non-null int64
hatchback      804 non-null int64
sedan          804 non-null int64
wagon          804 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(17)
memory usage: 113.1 KB

#VIF:

[5.9882999105246935,
 13.522607316383963,
 10.893965772667245,
 4.564742540402573,
 2.8815915938492838,
 3.6030229813600663]
```

Answer (score 0):

The variance inflation factor (VIF) is a measure of how much the variance of the estimates of all the parameters in a model increase when a specific variable is added, compared to the estimates of the parameters for a model where that variable is absent. The VIF is not giving you a comparison of the "colinearity between each two of the features", since it is not selecting two different features to compare.

The list of values you generate with this line:

`[variance_inflation_factor(X_train, j) for j in range(X_train.shape[1])]`

Is a list of VIF values that result when comparing the variance in parameter estimates for model that does not include **X_j** to the estimates for a model that does include **X_j**, *for all* **X_j**.

To be concrete, the first VIF in the list is `5.9882999105246935`, corresponding to the VIF for **X_mileage**. This tells you that the variance of the parameter estimates for the model that includes *all the other variables, plus* **X_mileage** is roughly 6 times higher than that for the model that does not include **X_mileage**. The increase in variance for **X_cylinder** is ~13.5 times higher, and so on.

Assessing the impact of multicollinearity is not a purely statistical question. That is, aside from the case of perfect multicollinearity (one variable perfectly predicts the value of another), there is no clear rule by which to say a variable should or should not be included in a model. You will see various guidelines offered, such as eliminating any variable with VIF > 5, or sometimes VIF > 10, but these are only suggestions (though often based on very good reasoning).